# What happened to the other super soldiers?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, captain-america-civil-war

In *Captain America: Civil War*, Bucky informed Cap that there are *other* Winter Soldiers or super soldiers. My question is what actually happened in the scene in which the other Winter Soldiers started attacking the doctors and guards?

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly, the narration was telling us the other super soldiers had problems with obedience, and that scene was simply to demonstrate how severe those problems were.

Comment: ohhhhh i see, thankyou for answering my question

Answer (score 8):

The other Winter Soldiers were being trained, by pitting them against Bucky, but it's clear they were nowhere near as tractable. When the doctor attempted to examine the soldier after the fight, he reacted (seemingly on instinct) and killed him. The rest of the soldiers then began attacking the guards, though it doesn't appear they were trying to escape. It appears they were merely venting their aggression at the nearest targets.

Given that all five of the subjects were in suspended animation in Siberia 20+ years later, we can assume that HYDRA figured out how to get them back under control at some point in the future. But when Steve asks Bucky if Zemo can control them, his response is something like "close enough", which implies that even now the control over these other soldiers is not as complete as his own.

Comment: It was 25 years later, at most.

Comment: wow, thank you for the complete answer :D